# save output on multiple files

Tags: io-redirection, output

I'm trying to send disk space update to multiple files so that one file will have current update which will get overwritten every hours and another file can have all the updates where it appends the output everytime it runs. but its adding output only on the file where it appends but not in the first file(/tmp/daily..)

code *italic*

```
filename=$(date +"%d_$m-%H:%M")
df -kh  > /tmp/daily"$filename".txt >> /tmp/grand.txt
```

Is there anyway I can have these where first file(/tmp/daily...) will be overwritten with latest output and second file (/tmp/grand.txt) will append whenever it executes?

ARthur

Answer (score 1):

```
df -kh | tee -a /tmp/grand.txt > /tmp/daily"$filename".txt
```

To output the same data to more than one place, you must duplicate that data. This is what `tee` does.

In the pipeline above, `tee` gets the output of `df`.  It then appends it to the `grand.txt` file and also passes a copy of the data to its standard output stream.  That output stream is redirected to the daily file with a truncating output redirection.

Alternatively,

```
df -kh | tee /tmp/daily"$filename".txt >> /tmp/grand.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda. The first one worked. thanks for your quick helped as it saved my day.

Comment: @ratheeshp Good! You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).